# How to loop object and get value from an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question about how to loop an object in typescript and to get the value that I want.

my object looks like this:

```
mockdata = {

 "subobj1": {
   "order": 1
   "value": "abc"
 },
 "subobj2": {
   "order": 2
   "value": "aaa"
 },
  ...


}
```

I want to loop this object and only get the subobject, if order == 1

```
what I expect is to get object

"subobj1": {
   "order": 1
   "value": "abc"
 }
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the object using [`for in syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and find the respective value!

```js
const mockdata = {

  "subobj1": {
    "order": 1,
    "value": "abc"
  },
  "subobj2": {
    "order": 2,
    "value": "aaa"
  },

}
let output;
for (const property in mockdata) {
  if (mockdata[property].order === 1) {
    output = {
      [property]: mockdata[property]
    }
    break;
  }
}


console.log('result', output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty slim way to do it. I usually use `Object.keys` or `.entries` to all my obj for loops

```js
const arrOfOrderEqualToOne = Object.entries(mockdata).filter(([key, value]) => value.order === 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    let mockdata = {

 "subobj1": {
   "order": 1,
   "value": "abc"
 },
 "subobj2": {
   "order": 2,
   "value": "aaa"
 },
}
let temp;
Object.keys(mockdata).forEach(key=>{
  if(mockdata[key].order==1){
    temp=mockdata[key]
  }
})

console.log(temp)
```